# Issue with getting a variable to increment correctly

Tags: c#, xna

Im making an educational game for my final year project and am experiencing a bit of a bug when it comes to incrementing a value when my player box has collided with another items box. The bug comes when my player has died and then resets, the first item is collected fine but then the program seems to skip the next if statement and draws out the third item instead of the second.

I have added the code I believe where the issue lies below.

LevelManager.cs

```
                for (int x = hints.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--)
            {
                hints[x].Update(gameTime);
                if (player.CollisionRectangle.Intersects(
                    hints[x].CollisionRectangle))
                {
                    hints.RemoveAt(x);
                    player.Hint++;
                }
            }
```

Game1.cs

```
 if ((gameState == GameState.Playing) ||
            (gameState == GameState.PlayerDead) ||
            (gameState == GameState.GameOver))
        {
            spriteBatch.Begin(
          SpriteSortMode.BackToFront,
          BlendState.AlphaBlend);

            TileMap.Draw(spriteBatch);
            player.Draw(spriteBatch);
            LevelManager.Draw(spriteBatch);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(
                pericles8,
                "Score: " + player.Score.ToString(),
                scorePosition,
                Color.White);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(
                pericles8,
                "Lives Remaining: " + player.LivesRemaining.ToString(),
                livesPosition,
                Color.White);

            if (player.Hint == 1)
            {
                spriteBatch.DrawString(
                    pericles8,
                    "Hint: " + "Antivirus is needed to protect your PC",
                    HintLocation,
                    Color.Black);
            }

            if (player.Hint == 2)
            {
                spriteBatch.DrawString(
                    pericles8,
                    "Hint: " + "When the first virus was created, it changed the name of floppy disks that were infected",
                    HintLocation,
                    Color.Black);
            }

            if (player.Hint == 3)
            {
                spriteBatch.DrawString(
                    pericles8,
                    "Hint: " + "Blue Whale is NOT the name of a virus and also whilst adware is annoying, it is not considered a virus",
                    HintLocation,
                    Color.Black);
            }

            if (player.Hint == 4)
            {
                spriteBatch.DrawString(
                    pericles8,
                    "Hint: " + "By having a firewall up, you lock all backdoors into your PC." + "\n" + "Also by staying clear of sites you dont know, you lower the chance of viruses getting into your PC" + "\n"
                    + "However you should install relevant protection to increase your chance of not getting viruses",
                    HintLocation,
                    Color.Black);
            }
            spriteBatch.End();
        }

        if (gameState == GameState.PlayerDead)
        {
            player.Hint = 0;
        }
```

Any help that can be given would be greatly appreciated
Cheers

Comment: it s possible that player hit two objects in same loop, so it will increase twice. try putting loop break after `player.Hint++; `

Comment: I have removed tag(s) from your question's title based on  _[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)_ where the consensus is **no** _they should not_.

Comment: Unrelated, but you seem to have too much faith in firewalls.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see bug in code snippets that you provided. All I can say you can set breakpoint on the line

```
player.Hint++;
```

(or event better inside setter of Hint property) and see when and why it changed to 3.

Comment: This is not an answer, and should be a comment